# Cachear usuarios logueados Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cache

Estoy intentando que mi página de Wordpress vaya más rápido, por lo que me instalé el plugin `Cache Enabler` .

Lo que tiene que pasar es que en la carpeta `wp-content/cache` se cree una carpeta llamada `/cache-enabler` y dentro de esta se creen las páginas cacheadas.

Esto en principio funciona, pero solo con visitantes de la página que no estén logueados...

¿Qué puedo hacer para que cacheen a los usuarios logueados también?

Comment: ¿El plugin no tiene opciones de configuración que hagan eso que quieres? Debería tener esas opciones, supongo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por contestar! No, no tiene esa función el plugin...

Comment: Parece que el plugin [sí tiene una forma de configurar esa funcionalidad](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cached-page-showed-to-logged-in-users/). Recomendaría que preguntes en el módulo de soporte del mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres cachear a lo usuarios logueados tienes que cambiar de plugin. De momento no incorpora esa función. Si necesitas una alternativa gratuita te recomiendo la versión lite del plugin **Swift Performance**.

Lo puedes descargar desde el repositorio de WordPress: [Swift Performance Lite](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/swift-performance-lite/)

Si decides instalarlo, **puedes activar la caché para usuarios logueados** de la siguiente manera:

Vete a *Herramientas* > *Switf Performance Lite* > *Settings* > *Caching* > *General* y **activa la caché**:

[image: Panel de control de Switf Performance Lite]

Una vez activado, se desplegaran todas las opciones del plugin. Entre ellas: *Enable caching for logged in users*:

[image: Panel de control de Switf Performance Lite]

Deberás activarla también. Para acabar, haz scroll hasta el principio de la página de opciones y pulsa en "*Save Changes*"

Hay otros plugins de caché que te ofrecen esta opción, pero son premiun. Espero que te sea de ayuda :)